# Rails add route for additional method action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have read some other questions and answers on this topic, yet I'm an still really confused.

I have a user model with the standard functions. I want to add a page similar to edit/update that allows the user to connect with APIs.

I built the following functions into my controller:

```
def deviceConnectEdit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def deviceConnectUpdate
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.deviceConnectUpdate_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Device Connected"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'deviceConnect'
  end
end
```

Very similar to the standard edit/update

I also built two files deviceConnectUpdate.html.erb and deviceConnectUpdate.html.erb (they have a

statement currently to see when they are called.

now when I run `rake routes`

```
      users GET     /users(.:format)                     users#index
      POST          /users(.:format)                     users#create
      new_user GET  /users/new(.:format)                 users#new
      edit_user GET /users/:id/edit(.:format)            users#edit
      user GET      /users/:id(.:format)                 users#show
      PUT           /users/:id(.:format)                 users#update
      DELETE        /users/:id(.:format)                 users#destroy
```

when I call `foobar/users/1/deviceConnectEdit` I receive the error that there are not matching routes.

How do I fix this and add routes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to declare the routes in your `config\routes.rb` file.

Also, if you want to use more idiomatic ruby (which you do), you should be using underscored method names, not camelCase.  e.g. `device_connect_edit` NOT `deviceConnectEdit`.  You'll run into headaches down the road if you don't conform to the convention (unless you have a very good reason for departing from it).  In that light I'll post the routes in idiomatic Ruby and hope you update your method names :-)

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'device_connect_edit'
    post 'device_connect_update'
  end
end
```

Also, you might want to strongly consider your design to have a separate `device` resource instead of tacking it on in the UsersController...

Comment: Thanks for all the info, you are completely correct. I'll make a device model. I'm new to ruby, so any advice is appreciated

Comment: I'd recommend going through the Rails guides as you get started. And then review your implementation as you finish to make sure you understand what's happening.  Start here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html and make note of resources, singular resources and nested resources.